# How to temporarily change values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a table that has the following information: ID, name, course_num, credits, grade and I need to calculate each student's GPA. The query should be simple however, grades is stored as an alphabetic character so I have to convert it before I can do any of the adding. How can I do this without modifying the values in the table?

A: 4.0; A-: 3.67; B+:3.33; B: 3; B-: 2.67; C+: 2.33; C: 2; C-: 1.67; D+: 1.33; D: 1; D-: 0.67; F: 0

I should point out that table I have with that information is the result of a subquery that joins 3 tables called student, takes, and course which store student info, grades, and course info respectively.

This will eventually be put inside a java method using JDBC

Here's the statement I tried that I know is off but I feel like it's on the right track?

```
SELECT ID, name, (sum( case grade
                      WHEN 'A' THEN 4
                      WHEN 'A-' THEN 3.67
                      WHEN 'B+' THEN 3.33
                      WHEN 'B' THEN 3
                      WHEN 'B-' THEN 2.67
                      WHEN 'C+' THEN 2.33
                      WHEN 'C' THEN 2
                      WHEN 'C-' THEN 1.67
                      WHEN 'D+' THEN 1.33
                      WHEN 'D' THEN 1
                      WHEN 'D-' THEN .67
                      WHEN 'F' THEN 0)*credits)/sum(credits)) GPA

FROM (SELECT takes.ID, name, cid, grade, credits
      FROM student Natural Join takes Natural Join course) subQ
GROUP BY ID;
```

I also have this solution but I'm not sure where I'd get the gpa# to plug in

```
SELECT takes.id, name, sum(credits * gpa#) / sum(credits) AS GPA
FROM takes NATURAL JOIN student NATURAL JOIN course
GROUP BY takes.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with your query. I just added `name` to the `group by` clause, modified the math and formatted it a little bit:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  `name`, 
  sum(
    case grade
      WHEN 'A' THEN 4
      WHEN 'A-' THEN 3.67
      WHEN 'B+' THEN 3.33
      WHEN 'B' THEN 3
      WHEN 'B-' THEN 2.67
      WHEN 'C+' THEN 2.33
      WHEN 'C' THEN 2
      WHEN 'C-' THEN 1.67
      WHEN 'D+' THEN 1.33
      WHEN 'D' THEN 1
      WHEN 'D-' THEN .67
      WHEN 'F' THEN 0
      ELSE 0
    end * credits
  ) / sum(credits) as GPA
FROM 
(
  SELECT takes.ID, name, cid, grade, credits
  FROM student 
  inner join takes 
  inner join course
) subQ
GROUP BY 
  ID,
  `name`;
```

Give it a shot and see how it all works out for you.

Comment: This works near perfect! A lot of them add up correctly but it skips 2 students and gets one student a 2.0 instead of a 4.0 and I can't find any logic errors in here...

Comment: Added a WHERE is not null and it fixed it right up! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sean Great job. If you find that one of the answers solved your problem, please feel free to mark them as accepted